# Show default.aspx page contact and last modified time information

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I provisioned a non publishing custom site. The home page is `default.aspx` which resides in all files and can be viewed from designer.

I want to get the value of this page contact and last modified date programmatically. Is this possible to do and how?

For a publishing site I know there is `contactfieldcontrol` to show it.

```
<sharepointportalwebcontrols:contactfieldcontrol webpart="true" runat="server" __webpartid="{CECDDC12-6DC9-4008-A9ED-26C86BF23015}"
        id="ContactFieldControl1" allowclose="False" allowconnect="False" allowedit="False"
        allowhide="False" allowminimize="False" allowremove="False" allowzonechange="False"
        frametype="None" isdisplayjobtitle="False" isdisplaypicture="True" title="Page Owner"
        wrap="False"></sharepointportalwebcontrols:contactfieldcontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using object model you can retrieve this as

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("default.aspx");
if(file.Exists) // here, this condition will return always false
{
    SPListItem item = file.Item;
    if(item != null)
    {
        //item["Created By"]
        //item["Modified By"]
        //item["Created"]
        //item["Modified"]
    }
}
```